# Does Stardew Valley have poweruser keyboard support?

Tags: stardew-valley, keyboard

I am *not* an experienced PC gamer but I *am* a software developer who tries to leave the keyboard as little as possible during the day. I've had a lot of trouble with this in Stardew Valley.

- The biggest pain point is rifling through the back half of my backpack.
- Some questions you can answer with "y"es/"n"o, others require clicking.
- Like watching TV.
- The "X" action is really ambiguous if I'm both holding an object and sometimes rather unsuccessfully trying to pick up an object. Or gift an object, or eat an object, etc.

Are there better keyboard solutions for these problems?

FWIW I'm running a Mac + Wineskin solution.

Comment: The game supposedly has good controller support, so I find it odd that there are things you can't do with just keyboard, but I have never played it with a controller so I can't confirm that it doesn't have same issues as using just keyboard.

Comment: you forgot to mention the issue when the character is nearby the mouse pointer, and you can't aim reliably using the direction the char is facing: if he's facing west but the mouse is just above him, when you use a tool it's going to hit north, not west ><

Answer (score 1):

Alas, it doesn't seem possible to eschew the mouse completely, but here's a handy trick for reorganizing your inventory:

1. Find a chest.
2. Click all the things you want in the top row of your inventory in your chest (for instance, four types of eggs).
3. Click the same number of slots in your top row to clear those spots.
4. Now click repeatedly in the upper-left box of the chest until everything is back in your inventory.

This saves you the hassle of dragging and dropping over and over again, and when you're done with the eggs, you can just do an inventory sort to get things back where they were.

Comment: Well thanks for posting the tip...  but if I need to reorganize things in the mine, leave the mine, trolley home, hop on my horse, find a chest, reorganize, hop back on my horse, trolley back to the mine, go down ~5 floors above where I was, and proceed, hardly counts as "good keyboard support".

Comment: I guess you could carry a chest around with you, and just plop it on the floor when you need it...  :D

Comment: Can you nest chests inside your backpack D:

Comment: Should I build a chest outside the mine????

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't dislodge and pick up a chest unless it's empty.  As for your other question, I did in fact have two chests outside the mines: One to dump my normal day-to-day stuff in and another to pick up my mine-related stuff out of.  I've relocated those chests since then, but they still serve the same purpose.  But obviously exiting the mines just to sort your inventory would be pretty silly.